# [SQL][Mariadb] High key/ low key with a date

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have a table that is actually like this

```
    CREATE TABLE a(
ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
SomeData VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_a_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I want to get rid of the auto-increment id by changing it with a key that uses a high key / low key system, as shown below:

```
ID : 1 -> ID : 201707130000000
ID : 2 -> ID : 201707130000001
ID : 3 -> ID : 201707140000000
ID : 4 -> ID : 201707140000001
ID : 7 -> ID : 201707140000002
```

Where the high key is the date, and the low key a simple counter with up to 7 significant digits.
How do I update the current table to achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? How are you going to assign new keys?

Comment: I want to do that because i think the use of the auto incremental id irrelevant, and want a id who have a meaning. To assign new key, i will use a tempory table, and then, just alter the current table.

Comment: How will you assign new keys in the future? There's still no additional meaning in the new key (which can't be derived from the old DATE/ID combination)

Comment: Simple : i will count the number of occurence for the current date in the database, then add it to the date to have a unique key. Wich this, i will not need a auto incremental ID neither a Date field (since i will already have the  data in the id field)

Comment: And when you need to get rows for a given date you apply some substring/cast on that column? Don't do it.

Comment: That was the idea. Do you have a alternative in mind that can remove the auto-incremental id and give meaning to the primary key?

Comment: leave the auto-increment and add a new column which has the default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). Create an index on this column and then you have all you need without making things too complicated.